# Kivy: Builder.load_file('*.kv') throws a FileNotFoundError when packaging app for Windows

Tags: python, windows, kivy, packaging

I am attempting to package my app for windows but I keep getting this error when running the .exe file generated.  The file does exist in the project directory and it works fine when running main.py directly.  In my main.py I called Builder.load_file('home_screen.kv'), which is where it seems to be throwing the error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
   File "site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 800, in run
   File "main.py", line 10, in build
   File "main.py", line 15, in __init__
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 288, in load_file
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home_screen.kv'
[3208] Failed to execute script main
```

This problem is not specific to home_screen.kv since even if I remove that line the following line, Builder.load_file('create_schedule.kv'), throws the same error.

Comment: Try adding the full path to the file. Eg.  "C:\full\path\to\file.kv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.spec` file add a line in the `Analysis` like:

```
datas=[('*.kv', '.')],
```

This will include the `home_screen.kv` (assuming it is in the same directory as your `main.py`).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to put the full path i.e. [('C:\\path\\home_screen.kv', '.')]