# Kivy to one exe can't find kv file

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I've seen some related questions here and tried every single solution I found like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359391/kivy-builder-load-file-kv-throws-a-filenotfounderror-when-packaging-app-fo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599799/main-kv-file-cant-be-found-in-pyinstaller-exe) for example, but I couldn't make that work. So the question is simple - after making single exe file from kivy it throws a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main2.kv'`. Exe file with related files works good but I don't know what am I doing wrong while building single exe.

My spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivymd.tools.packaging.pyinstaller import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
...
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
    ...
    # I tried to write here absolute path, relative path and this method
    datas=[('*.kv', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    ...
)

# I also tried to put import here - didn't help (when I did that I also tried to change the path in my .py file to 'Data\main2.kv')
# a.datas += [('main2.kv', 'D:\\prog\\Lotto\\main2.kv', 'DATA')]
...

# tried with Tree and without Tree
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('D:\\prog\\Lotto','Data'),
    ...
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    ...
```

In .py file I tried to add

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(sys._MEIPASS)
```

And

```
def resourcePath():
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."))
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(resourcePath())
    MainApp().run()
```

And tried both of above methods together - nothing. Also tried to change PyInstaller 3.6 to 3.5 version. I don't know what's the problem here, it's my first time trying to make exe file from Kivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few hours later finally I got that. I open my kv file as `file` first and then pass it to `Builder` to be able to set the encoding. In that case I just needed to define the path of `kv` file manually as `sys._MEIPASS + 'main2.kv'` and then it worked.

UPD: To make that work make few imports first:

```
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
```

and then at the end of your app just before MainApp.run() add this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # these lines should be added
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    ###
    MainApp().run()
```

When we build single .exe file it holds all files inside of it, so it unpacks it to some random temporary folder while running. `sys._MEIPASS` here is the path of that temp folder.

So that should work. If it still can't find files, you can try to change file path like this: for example, instead of `'example.kv'` write `sys._MEIPASS + '/' + 'example.kv'`.

Also make sure you've done everything right in the .spec file, so you should add your files to `datas` list in `Analysis` like this:

```
        a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             ...
             datas=[('main.kv', '.'), ('bg.png', '.'), ('CenturyGothic.ttf', '.'), ('finish.mp3', '.'), ('Logo.png', '.'),],
```

So if you have only `kv` file to add it would be:

```
datas=[('main.kv', '.')],
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me into the right direction. An additional thing I had to fix with my code: `Builder.load_file("some_file.kv")` can only be called after `resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put here my experience and how I could solve it. Following is my directory structure.

```
AppDir
|_ src
      |_ *.kv, *.py
|_ images
      |_ *.png
```

As suggested in above answer I did not do `resource_add_path` in my main (It did not work for me), instead just prepend `sys._MEIPASS` to kv file for `Builder.load_file`. But then you would face a problem, you will not be able to run it directly as a python script. I solved it by conditionally prepending path based on packaged binary or python script.

This is how I did it, in a `common_defines.py` file I defined `KV_DIRECTORY`

```
# common_defines.py
import os, sys

# Assuming all .kv files are in same directory as this file
KV_DIRECTORY = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# If the script is bundled with PyInstaller, override the path with _MEIPASS
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   # Bundled with PyInstaller
   KV_DIRECTORY = sys._MEIPASS
```

And wherever you want to load the kv file, load with file with `KV_DIRECTORY` prepended to file name.

For example

```
# some_file.py
import os
from kivy.lang import Builder
import common_defines

Builder.load_file(os.path.join(common_defines.KV_DIRECTORY, 'some_file.kv'))
```

This way kv file path for both scenarios will be set correctly.
Then you can just run following command from `AppDir` to generate executable.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-data "src\*.kv;." --add-data "images\*.png;images" src\main.py
```